# "npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/" is not working in windows bat file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, npm

I create a.bat on windows 7, the content of a.bat is:

```
@echo off
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and then run a.bat, but not working, I find the word "set" is special keyword for npm and bat, is there any methods to resolve this question?

Comment: Does anyone else just come to this post every time they want to see what the npm registry url is? haha

Comment: FYI: I needed the .com version of the registry: i.e. `https://registry.npmjs.com/` rather than `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: @infl3x why? what are the differences?

Comment: @kevingilbert100 `npm config get registry` to know the registry URL

Comment: @kevingilbert100 yes xD

Comment: @Sridhar Nope. That only provides the current set registry, not the "official" npm registry.

Comment: Had to change from `https` to `http`

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You shouldn't change the npm registry using `.bat` files. 
Instead try to use modify the `.npmrc` file which is the configuration for `npm`.
The correct command for changing registry is

`npm config set registry <registry url>`

you can find more information with `npm help config` command, also check for privileges when and if you are running `.bat` files this way.

Comment: may be the method I used is not suitable for my question, but still thanks for your answer:)

Comment: @MarcellodeSales try `npm config set registry=<registry url>`

Comment: The `config` part is not necessary, can run just `npm get registry` to see your current, and `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` to set it back to the default.

Comment: is npm config set registry <local node_modules folder> possible. If i don't want to download anything from internet and all artifacts are within the app.

Answer (score 139):

We can also run npm install with `registry` options for multiple custom registry URLs.

```
npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ 
npm install --registry=https://custom.npm.registry.com/
```

Comment: running `npm install` while `.npmrc` is set for a private artifactory was causing a lot of pains. This has saved me a couple of hours 

Answer (score 63):

You can change using the .bat make sure you run the call command prior, hopefully this helps anyone in future making similar .bat commands

```
call npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 37):

On version 4.4.1, you can use:

```
npm config set @myco:registry=http://reg.example.com
```

Where @myco is your package scope. You can install package in this way:

```
npm install @myco/my-package
```

ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Answer (score 35):

1. **Set npm registry globally**

   use the below command to modify the .npmrc config file for the logged in user

   `npm config set registry <registry url>`

   *Example:*  `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

---

2. **Set npm registry Scope**

   Scopes allow grouping of related packages together. Scoped packages will be installed in a sub-folder under **node_modules** folder.

   *Example*: **node_modules/@my-org/packagaename**

   To set the scope registry use:  `npm config set @my-org:registry http://example.reg-org.com`

   To install packages using scope use: `npm install @my-org/mypackage`

   whenever you  install any packages from scope **@my-org** npm will search in the registry setting linked to scope **@my-org** for the registry url.

---

3. **Set npm registry locally for a project**

   To modify the npm registry only for the current project. create a file inside the root folder of the project as `.npmrc`

   Add the below contents in the file

```
   registry = 'https://registry.npmjs.org/'
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to `npm config set registry https://...`, but when I've doing `npm config get registry` it was returning `http://...`, and problem was that someone commited `.nmprc` with `http://...` and it takes precedence over global config. I spend like good 10 minutes until I understand what happens with help of your post :)

Answer (score 22):

Probably I am too late to answer. But if anybody need it, following works fine, as I have used it a lot of times.

```
npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

Answer (score 6):

On npm version 3.7.3

`npm set registry=http://whatever/`

Answer (score 1):

By executing your .bat you are setting config for only that session not globally. When you open and another cmd prompt and run `npm install` that config will not set for this session so modify your .bat file as

```
@echo off
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
@cmd.exe /K
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2.name can no longer contain capital letters
```

don't use capital letters for your package:

```
npm install --save uex
```

use this:

```
npm install --save vuex
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to change npm registry using `.bat` file as [Gntem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333329/gntem) pointed out.
But I understand that you need the ability to automate changing registries.
You can do so by having your `.npmrc` configs in separate files (say *npmrc_jfrog* & *npmrc_default*) and have your `.bat` files do the copying task.

For example (in Windows): 
Your *`default_registry.bat`* will have

```
xcopy /y npmrc_default .npmrc
```

and your *`jfrog_registry.bat`* will have

```
xcopy /y npmrc_jfrog .npmrc
```

**Note:** `/y` suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

This will make sure that all the config properties (*registry, proxy, apiKeys, etc.*) get copied over to `.npmrc`.

You can read more about xcopy [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).