# How to reset the npm registry in global npm config

Tags: npm, registry, npm-install

Is there any way to change or reset the global npm registry.

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385092/npm-config-set-registry-https-registry-npmjs-org-is-not-working-in-windows

Answer (score 321):

Run the following command in your terminal to revert back to the default regsitry

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or

```
npm config delete registry
```

[NPM CONFIG DOCS](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config)

Comment: You can setup a per repo .npmrc file as well with the following: registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: It needs to be a full URL though. `registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

If you are on windows, other than setting the registry, you can also delete the `.npmrc` file to reset the registry.

You can find this file at  `C:\Users\<Your User Name>\.npmrc`

Comment: The same file also exists on Linux as `~/.npmrc` and deleting it also works

Answer (score 17):

Sets a configuration key to a value

```
npm config set <key> <value> [-g|--global]
```

Gets the value of an existing configuration key

```
npm config get <key>
```

Deletes the key from all configuration files.

```
npm config delete <key>
```

Lists all the config settings,could be used to check for existing config entries

```
npm config list
```

Opens the config file in an editor.

```
npm config edit
```

All that would help make changes to the npm registry

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Yes...

You can use this

```
$(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

Answer (score 2):

What I accidentally tried and it's working fine is

```
npm config set registry
```

Just it, without any additional parameters.

Comment: I found it also worked to have an empty .npmrc in the directory I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac,

Go to /Users/<user_name>

Create a .npmrc file (or edit if already created)

These are the default values which I change usually for most of my projects:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
legacy-peer-deps=false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I had to use a private NPM registry for *security reasons* and while switching projects I had to change my registry and found that I was unable to! A requirement of the private registry was to be on a VPN network so to be able to connect to the private registry.

**Command I was trying to run**
`npx sb init --builder webpack5`

I was trying to install storybook in an existing project.

I tried and failed by:

1. `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org` commands even with `--location=` set to project, user, global
2. setting `.npmrc` with `npm_config_registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` value in multiple locations
3. even `yarn` wouldn't change the registry and I also tried to use the yarn specific commands as well `yarn config set ...`
4. restarting my system multiple times and re-trying all of the above in different ways

Information about my environment:

1. OSX, NVM (Node Version Manager), using `npm` not `yarn`

**What ended up fixing my problem**
2. I ended up reconnecting to the VPN so that when I ran my `npx ...` command from above it would still download the packages through my private registry
3. `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` I removed the installed files and lockfile
4. I disconnected from my VPN and re-installed packages with the same `npx ...` command
5. I see now that the packages are properly pulling from `https://registry.npmjs.org`

For some reason NPM wanted to resolve *something* from the private registry I had before finally using the newly configured public registry.

Might be a bug with NPM that I do not have the experience nor time to troubleshoot though I wanted to share my experience here in hopes it will help someone with a similar experience.