# ng update fails with "404 not found" for private packages

Tags: angular, npm

I want to update angular app from version 13 to 14. This also includes a private package
`company-package` which can be found under `company.com/...` url.
Sadly the pacakge is not scoped, it doesn't start with an `@` ...

npm version is on `16.x.x` in case it is relevant.

If I run the `ng update ...` command I get following message:

`Migration failed: 404 Not Found -  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/company-package` ... which makes sense, since it is not on npmjs.

I also have an `.npmrc` file which is used for installing the package, this worked. otherwise I wouldn't have been able to work on this in the past.

Contents of `.npmrc` file:

```
registry=https://company.com/repository/npm-all/
//company.com/repository/npm-all/:_auth=ABCDEFGH12345
```

I tried setting the registry with `npm config set registry company.com...`

When I messed with the npm config, I managed to get this error: `An unhandled exception occurred: 403 Forbidden - GET https://company.com/...repository/npm-all/@angular%2fcli`

To me this looks like angular update can't correctly resolve the package used in `.npmrc` file. Is there any solution to this? How can I tell angular upgrade to fetch this package from a different host?

Or did I just screw up my config for npm? I noticed when I run `npm install` it also fetches now everything from company website... I tried resetting it based on this question but no luck so far [How to reset the npm registry in global npm config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136444/how-to-reset-the-npm-registry-in-global-npm-config)

Comment: Is your `company-package` scoped? Ie named something like `@your-company/company-package` Because that would be the typical approach. What backend are you using to host your company package? When you do `npm config set registry company.com` you are infact completely disabling the default `npmjs.org` registry and directing ALL requests to your own registry. Your backend may not support this for packages that aren't located there ....

Comment: And please also show this "`.npmrc` file for installing the package"

Comment: Sadly not (and since it is not my own company, I can't tell them to change this :/ ) I also just realized that I have now everything pointing to the company registry... I tried deleting it, but it still points to the companys registry when I run npm install. Will edit main post now.

Comment: Well, also your project's .npmrc let's everything (within the project) point to that registry. No big difference there.  And also the `package-lock.json` determines from where a package is installed. So if you installed a package from a `https://example.com/registy` it will be stored with that url in the `package-lock.json` so for future reinstalls those packages will always be taken form the same source

Comment: Not sure thogh, how `ng update` does (or doesn't) take into account an project-specific npmrc file

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to log the registry config in your project directory:

```bash
npm config get registry
```

Then compare the result with when your run the command outside of your repo.

If you want set the package registry back to to npmjs:

```bash
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I believe it is not possible to set the registry of unscoped packages in `.npmrc` file without effecting everything else.

I suggest to install your package directly using the clone url to avoid this issue. Your `package.json` would look like the following in this case:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "your-package-name": "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies ok here I see how this might work.. but how can I set a ausername + pw with this approach? (Which won't be commited to git, as it would be with npmrc file)?

Comment: @cloned easiest would be to use ssh so you dont have to deal with username/password