# Installing npm package fails with 404

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

Using the command prompt, I am trying to install angular CLI and it fails. I have npm version 5.5.1 and node version v8.9.1. I am trying to install angular cli using the command

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

and it fails with the error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

I look at the log file and I see its trying to fetch the package from a location that doesn't exist. Not sure from where it gets pulled. How do I fix this location path and install angular cli. Same happens when I try to install typescript or any other npm package. all of them try to install from the location mentioned below and it fails with 404

```
8 http fetch GET 404 
       http://nuget.feed.xyz.corp:8729/npm/FeedNPM/@angular%2fcli 109ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest 404 Not Found: 
     @angular/cli@latest
10 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: What's your question? It looks like @angular/cli doesn't exist.

Comment: See this question's top answer, and use the default npm registry location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385092/npm-config-set-registry-https-registry-npmjs-org-is-not-working-in-windows . Registry:  https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: Yep, That was it. Can't thank you enough!! Your answer made my day!

Answer (score 89):

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

[NPM registry documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer - Weird took me a while to find through searches thanks

Comment: Should I use http or https?

Comment: Looks lie it's redirecting to https so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 22):

Try first this commands (in windows run as administrator)

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

if still not working let's update NPM and nodejs by running this commands

```
npm -g install npm
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
```

then try to run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This should solve this problem

Comment: When I do the above options, I got rollbackFailedOptional and ETIMEOUT later. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in which OS? if you are using windows just then you can try to unintall and try again may be this works.

Answer (score 15):

in my case it was `.npmrc` file in my project dir, which kept overwriting my global registry url. As soon as I deleted it, I could finally use `npm install`

Comment: Same here. Had to delete .npmrc (was trying to install private package) , then do npm install and once it worked I restored the .npmrc back to the project

Comment: I had an issue with my .npmrc file. There were some mandatory entries that I had missed.

Answer (score 5):

**Add a `.npmrc` file in the root of the project. `.npmrc` will look like below -**

> @xy:registry=https://xyz.jfrog.io/xyz/api/npm/npm-local/
> @xy-app:registry=https://xyz.jfrog.io/xyz/api/npm/npm-local/

And Delete all the field eg - email , auth etc.
Find out what is the registry url of your application and put it into the registry.

Then run command -  `npm install`
And it will work.

Answer (score 4):

It was giving the same error for me when I use office network/vpn as they have 'umbrella' DNS security shield. To solve this issue, connect to personal network and type the below commands:

```
    npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
    npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative, another option to avoid 404 npm error

> check if your terminal is in the root directory, if not your npm scripts will not execute
>   because it will not be able to see the **package.json**

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours on this.

I had to follow the below steps to get it to work (mac).

Delete my LOCAL (not project) `.npmrc` by running:

```
rm /Users/<NAME>/.npmrc
```

Then set the registry:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then follow the steps for logging in to npm:

```
npm login
```

Check what's in your config list by running:

```
npm config list
```

It should look like this:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken = (protected)
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 3):

When I looked for .npmrc in home folder I couldn’t find it.

But and after running:

```bash
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with a private package.
Need to:

- `npm adduser`
- `npm login`

Answer (score 0):

1. change your access level to public. type this in the terminal

```
npm --access=public
```

2. install your angular.

```
sudo npm install @ngular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that's a typo error:
change `trct-js-sdk` to `trtc-js-sdk` saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was as follows because I had a dependency on a ***private package***. If you see the dependency in package.json defined in the format ***@scope/package***, then @scope tells you that it's a scoped package that might be private.

1. Get the private package owner to grant you access to the package
2. Upgrade npm
3. Upgrade node
4. Add registry using HTTPS (not HTTP), e.g. `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org`
5. Do "npm login"
6. Now run the build

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

I got

> error 404  'dotnev@*' is not in this registry.

Deleted .npmrc file in 2 folders back over my project root
and then in the project root folder typed:

```
npm i dotenv
```

copied from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall NPM & nodejs and install the right way NPM (Ubuntu)

sudo with npm is not recommended

To Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

1. Followed by proper installation

> curl -o-
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

2. To confirm open a new terminal run:

> $ command -v nvm

3. Latest LTS release of NodeJS:

> $ nvm install --lts

4. Set default environment

> $ nvm alias default lts/*

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org` and then update your npm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What did I do?

First I deleted the .npmrc file in home/user

- `ls -a`
- `sudo rm .npmrc`

Then I downgraded my npm to a lower version

- `npm install -g npm@8.19.4`

Then in my application I deleted the `node_module` package and runned the `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

The top most answer is correct and will solve your issue with 404 error. Just wanted to add to this answer that helped me resolve the issue in my case.

Post setting the registry,

Do a npm cache clean and restart your system. Now, try re-installing the package, it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35266885)

Answer (score -1):

It is an network error , check your network connection and try to install it again.

Answer (score -1):

the only command line "npm -g install npm" solved the issue for me!
the following link can be helpful to dig deep for a better understanding.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "The following link"? Where?