# ArcGIS JS API 4.7 and NPM error

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to install ArcGIS JS API 4.7 with npm (for a Vue.JS application), and when running
`npm install arcgis-js-api`

I am getting a NPM error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @dojo/i18n@~0.6.0
```

I am using the latest version of Node (v10), but I also tried it with v9 and v6.

Has anyone faced it in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are using a different NPM mirror? Maybe for private packages?
Does the answer provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520181/installing-npm-package-fails-with-404/47521589#47521589) help you?

Comment: It was a problem with NPM indeed. That answer didn't quite work but after uninstall and reinstalling NPM I managed to install my dependencies. Thank you.