# npm not installing packages, shows E404

Tags: npm

I am new to node and trying to install express package using npm. It throws error E404. I saw the log file and it is as follow:

**Error**

> 2 info using npm@5.6.0
>
> 3 info using node@v8.11.1
>
> 4 verbose npm-session fe4d5b2eef34bf8f
>
> 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
>
> 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
>
> 7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.com/express 639ms
>
> 8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express@latest 404 Not Found:
> express@latest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing npm package fails with 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520181/installing-npm-package-fails-with-404)

Comment: shorter the error log.

Comment: @Delena, I did what was explained in that link, but it did not work for me.

Comment: The error log, line 7 shows the URL it tried to find express, it is present there yet it shows me E404 Not Found.