# Can't Install npm Express

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to execute this:

```
$ npm install express --save
```

And I'm getting this log:

> npm
>   ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network request
>   to http://npm.jibo.com:8080/express failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   10.0.0.106:8080 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or
>   have bad network settings. npm ERR! network  npm ERR! network If you
>   are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy'
>   config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

As far I can see, my npm or node is pointing to a server of a client npm.jibo.com:8080, how can I reset that value?

I have no Idea what I'm doing with Node and npm because I'm new to this, and the first time I did something in my Mac was like "execute all this form jibo" and the project will work.

I have tried to look for a solution, but nothing points me in the right direction, probably because I'm asking wrong questions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help as some one pointed:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

That instruction solved the problem because the file .npmrc was pointing to npm.jibo.com:8080.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you running behind some proxy? If yes try to set proxy as npm config set proxy http://<proxy ip>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy ip>:<port>

Comment: please share your npm config. You can either look in your /Users/<<user>>/.npmrc file or simply execute npm config list

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385092/npm-config-set-registry-https-registry-npmjs-org-is-not-working-in-windows)? Its hard to conclude do you want to resolve the issue by debuging what is happening with registry you mentioned, or you just want to change it?

Comment: @fabi_k in that file was the problem so thanks!!

Comment: @cool your link pointed me to the solution so thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the community.

The solution is here:

["npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/" is not working in windows bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385092/npm-config-set-registry-https-registry-npmjs-org-is-not-working-in-windows)

And my  /Users/<>/.npmrc file was pointing as far I understand to a private server repo.

Hope this help.